# Perl regex tr function in PHP

Tags: php, regex, perl, tr

I use `perl` mostly and it has a useful function to change charaterst to others, the `tr`:

```
 $str =~ tr/[ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ]/[AEIOOOUUU]/;
```

Now I need to implement this into `PHP`, but I found only the `str_replace` function witch change only one-by-one, like this:

```
$str = str_replace('Á', 'A', $str);
$str = str_replace('É', 'E', $str);
// etc...
```

Is there in PHP something one-line-solution like in Perl?

Comment: You may use `preg_replace` with arrays as search and replacement arguments.

Comment: `str_replace` accept array too

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, true. Still, I guess it is not what is expected.

Comment: @netdjw: Since you accepted anubhava's suggestion, please consider using `str_replace` solution as [it is said](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#49722) (I did not test) to be more efficient than `strtr` with long texts and large arrays.

Comment: @stribizhev: `str_replace` is good solution too as you said, but anubhava's solution is simplier I think. Thank you for your time and efforts to find these ways.

Comment: Perl's `tr///` operator *doesn't* accept regex patterns, only lists of characters. Your example happens to work because the translated characters are in the same position in the list as their corresponding originals. But it will also convert `[` to `[` and `]` to `]` so the brackets are superfluous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP use [`strtr` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) like this for translating characters:

```
$str = 'ÁÉÍ foo ÖŐÚÜŰ bar';
echo strtr($str, array('Á' => 'A', 'É' => 'E', 'Í' => 'I', 'Ó' => 'O', 
                       'Ö' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U'));
//=> AEI foo OOUUU bar
```

Comment: Just FYI: [`str_replace` is said](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#49722) to be more efficient than `strtr` with long texts and large arrays.

Comment: Is this a case of long text? OP is calling `tr` in perl which does char by char translation

Comment: btw that comment you quoted was posted 10 years ago

Comment: @stribizhev: about performances, you should take a look at this little test: https://eval.in/485638 (keep in mind that `str_replace` search all the string for each array item when `strtr` or `iconv` search the string only once for all items at the same time). Possible that `strtr` was slower in older PHP versions.

Comment: I think you should post that on that PHP Web page :)